# Updates to reputation do not show up under the ACHIEVEMENTS menu

Tags: bug, reputation, notifications, top-bar

Not sure if this is the right forum, but after the last failover test, 
updates to reputation do not show up under the ACHIEVEMENTS menu.

Also, it used to be that my rep. on meta and mse were the same, now the meta
is out of sync.

I don't particularly care about these things, but I presume it reflects a code/db change or similar that someone cares about.

I have cleared my Firefox cache and the problem remains.

I have logged in using Chrome and the problem remains.

Comment: http://shouldiblamecaching.com/

Comment: @900sit-upsaday: I did clear my Firefox cache... Is there some other cache I should be aware of?

Comment: I have that happening too, copper.hat, which is why I came to Meta to post as a bug. You did it for both of us. I also have a lingering green box containing $15$, and a lingering red box indicating a "new comment". I've clicked on both dozens of times, they keep reappearing "as new" whenever I refresh the page. Same "accepted" question, same message. This all started before the last "read only" interruption to the site, and persisted after that interruption ended.

Comment: My meta & mse rep. are now the same again. The ACHIEVEMENTS menu is still missing some stuff...

Comment: I meant SE cache (which you can do nothing about), not your browser's cache. Various updates tend to go out of whack after failover exercises.

Comment: @900sit-upsaday: I was thinking locally and acting globally :-).

Comment: meta.SE: [Achievements dropdown not matching actual reputation since read-only time](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238156/achievements-dropdown-not-matching-actual-reputation-since-read-only-time)

Comment: Some items still do not show in the ACHIEVEMENTS list. It does not matter to me, but someone might care.

Comment: This is also a symptom of our server-side caching layer - should be fixed now!

Comment: @JarrodDixon: Thanks!

Comment: @Jarrod: So "900" was right? :-)

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Cache is always a problem for me :-).

Comment: @copper.hat: Maybe get another job (part time, of course), one that pays in cache?

Comment: @AsafKaragila: I guess cache has a whole new meaning with Bitcoin and its ilk?

Comment: I have no idea. I was playing on the similarity to cash. I am not too familiar with cryptocoin lingo...

Comment: @AsafKaragila: I was playing on same :-). Walmart sells Bitcoin mining boxes now, presumably with lots of (real) cache.

Comment: What happens when these machines halt? Do we say they hit the wall?

Comment: @AsafKaragila: They go into withdrawal :-).